# What do you think is the best way to segment a multispectral aerial image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

My goal is to perform fields segmentation of aerial imagery. Different crops have different colors and seem to be a good subject to segmentation.
Images contain 5 spectral components R, G, B, IR1, and IR2 (IR - Infra Red).

Here are the example images (5 channels of the same ground area):
[**>>Sample images<<**](http://imgur.com/xJkAbsl,tFv8Tre,sMeusuI,tpmzemZ,LzejhQs#0)

My idea was to use some kind of color image gradient and then perform Watershed on it but this leaves me with over-segmented image. Maybe I can make some kind of stochastic watershed by repeated addition of random noise to the original gradient image and then perform the Watershed for every noisy gradient image. Maybe I could then use the common ridges in all watersheds as final ridges?
 Any kind of help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about region growth algorithm on all 5 channels: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region_growing

With similarity measures based on euclidean distances between 5-dimensional (R G B IR1 IR2) vectors at each pixels.

Comment: This looks like an easy solution but the problem I have with this is that I don't have the seeds - it should be unsupervised process. Are you aware of a method to automatically determine good seeds?

Comment: you want to seed from places where there are small changes, i.e. where local gradient is small. There are many ways to do this. One examples: compute for each pixel the total variance of the neighboring 9 pixels. To do this, you construct a 9x5 matrix, call it `X`, where each row is the feature vector for a neighbor pixel, then you simple do `trace(cov(X))`. You want to find pixels where the total variance is small as seed. Also feel free to change window size.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using [logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) for some work. It's part of the set of general linear models, if you care about that sort of thing.

I've only done the two-class case, but the multi-class case is also implemented in MATLAB with `mnrfit`. [here is the help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mnrfit.html) Look under multinomial case.

You have to train the model (You'll need to have the true classes for a some pixels/ an image.). Then you use the estimated parameters to estimate classes for a new image.

Some stumbling blocks: 
 - data is in vectors, not in matrices 
 
 - you need to normalize your images

Comment: Thanks, I will have to read more about this and let you know the result.